# how to pass a varible in api link url in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the below API i wanted to replace *chicken* with my *ingredient* variable value.

```
var ingridient = ref("chicken");

https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=chicken&app_id=MY_API_ID&app_key=MY_API_KEY
```

Comment: Then replace it then. What's your problem

Comment: https://www.tutorialstonight.com/javascript-string-format.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i was using composition API of Vue JS for that reason only **${ingridient}** was not working for me. In composition API any variable with reactive *ref* provides an object. so for retrieving my *ingridient* value i need to call the value by **${ingridient.value}**.

```
var ingridient = ref("chicken");

https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=${ingridient.value}&app_id=MY_API_ID&app_key=MY_API_KEY
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```js
var url = "https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=chicken&app_id=MY_API_ID&app_key=MY_API_KEY";

console.log(url);

url = url.replace("chicken","grilledChicken");

console.log(url);
```

In your case: `url = url.replace("chicken", ref("chicken"));`